# trying to allow certain contacts to ring even the phone is in silent mode

Tags: android

I am trying to allow certain contacts to ring even the phone is in silent mode. When the first call comes after installing the app the phone is not ringing but later on wards it is working perfectly.... Is there any problem in the code...

```
      package com.cnu.incoming;


      import android.app.PendingIntent;
      import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
      import android.content.Context;
      import android.content.Intent;
      import android.hardware.Sensor;
      import android.hardware.SensorEvent;
      import android.hardware.SensorEventListener;
      import android.hardware.SensorManager;
      import android.media.AudioManager;
      import android.os.Bundle;
      import android.telephony.SmsManager;
      import android.telephony.TelephonyManager;
      import android.util.Log;
      import android.widget.Toast;

      public class IncomingCall extends BroadcastReceiver{


      private Context context;
      private String PhNumber;
      private int ringcheck=0;
      String state=null;
      Bundle bundle=null;



@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
     AudioManager maudio=(AudioManager)context.getSystemService(context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
        bundle = intent.getExtras();
        this.context = context;


        if(null == bundle)
                return;

        Log.i("IncomingCallReceiver",bundle.toString());

        state = bundle.getString(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE);

        Log.i("IncomingCallReceiver","State: "+ state);

        if(state.equalsIgnoreCase(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE_RINGING))
        {
                check();
                if(PhNumber.equals("+919876543210"))
                makeitNormal();
                PhNumber = bundle.getString(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_INCOMING_NUMBER);

                Log.i("IncomingCallReceiver","Incomng Number: " + PhNumber);

                String info = "Detect Calls Incoming number: " + PhNumber;


                maudio.setRingerMode(AudioManager.RINGER_MODE_NORMAL);


        }

        Log.i("baddu gadu" ,"baddu gadu");

        if(state.equalsIgnoreCase(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE_OFFHOOK))
        {
            makeItSilent();
        }

        if(state.equalsIgnoreCase(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE_IDLE))
        {
            makeItSilent();
        }


}



private void check() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    AudioManager maudio=(AudioManager)context.getSystemService(context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
    ringcheck=maudio.getRingerMode();

}

private void makeitNormal() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    AudioManager maudio=(AudioManager)context.getSystemService(context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
    maudio.setRingerMode(AudioManager.RINGER_MODE_NORMAL);
    //Toast.makeText(context, "this is baradwaj", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

}


private void makeItSilent() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    AudioManager maudio=(AudioManager)context.getSystemService(context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
    int ringer=maudio.getRingerMode();
    if (ringcheck==AudioManager.RINGER_MODE_SILENT){

        maudio.setRingerMode(AudioManager.RINGER_MODE_SILENT);

    }else if(ringcheck==AudioManager.RINGER_MODE_NORMAL){
        maudio.setRingerMode(AudioManager.RINGER_MODE_NORMAL);
    }
    else if(ringcheck==AudioManager.RINGER_MODE_VIBRATE){
        maudio.setRingerMode(AudioManager.RINGER_MODE_VIBRATE);
    }

}

public void onAccuracyChanged(Sensor arg0, int arg1) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub


}
```

}